# Append an array of jquery-elements to an element in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of HTML elements that are created like this from a ajax request:

```
var instaCampaign = $j('#campaign').clone().empty()
    $j.each(items.slice(0, len), function (i, item) {
        var insta = instaCampaign.clone()
        .prop('href', item.link)
        .prop('target', '_blank')
        .data('created', parseInt(item.created_time + '000'))
        .data('sort', 0)
        .append(
            $j('<img/>').attr('src', item.images && item.images.standard_resolution.url),
            item.caption && $j('<p/>').html(item.caption.text),
            $j('<i/>').addClass('icon instagram white'));

        instagramItems.push(insta);

    });
```

I then try to add them to an object, like this:

```
for (var i = instagramItems.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    $j('#instagram-footer').append(instagramItems[i])
};
```

I can add other stuff to `#instagram-footer`, but this won't work for some reason. Why?

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: Provided you've initialized `instagramItems` with `[]` or similar, that should work. You'll have to work through it in the debugger, and/or create an [MCVE](/help/mcve) (ideally as a runnable Stack Snippet -- `<>` button).

Comment: You say this is an ajax call, do you wait for that to complete before running the second?

Comment: @Liam Just no data inside instagramFooter.

Comment: @Liam yes, I can see the data in there if I console.log(instagramItems)

Comment: Side note: It's not the problem, but the block following a control flow statement like `if` doesn't need a `;` after it.

Comment: So, just to clarify, you can see the instagramItems **at the point you want to append** them?

Comment: add a console.log in the for loop

Comment: What is `instaCampaign`? Also, what @AdamGoldman said, log what you're appending in your for loop and make sure it's valid

Comment: @AdamGoldman: Better yet, use the debugger built into the browser. No need to stumble about with a console.log torch when one can turn on the lights. :-)

Comment: @AdamGoldman yes, that worked, the items get logged.

Comment: @timothyclifford updated question.

Comment: @Himmators: The only remaining possibilities that come to mind are: 1. That `#instagram-footer` doesn't exist as of when you're doing this, 2. It does but something else replaces its content later, or 3. (With apologies) Observation error. The problem lies outside the code in the question. You'll have to create an [MCVE](/help/mcve) (during which you'll probably figure it out, but if not, then we have something we can help you with).

Comment: When you log item, what gets logged?

Comment: @T.J. I tested the first by loggin $j(#instagram-footer), I also checked that nothing was inside the object.

Comment: @Himmators: That still leaves #2 and #3 on my list. #2 in particular. But again: No need for all this logging: Use the fully-featured debugger built into your browser.

Comment: Here you go https://jsfiddle.net/woen2f5g/1/ looks to be working to me...

Comment: @timothyclifford [a.campaign.instagram, prevObject: x.fn.x.init[1], context: document]

Comment: T,J, When I log it, I can see that it has no content.

Comment: @Himmators: *"2. It does [exist] **but something else replaces its content later**"* Note the word "later". E.g.: Your things are being appended, but then erased by other code afterward.